# Questions about tx_description field in URI

Tags: blockchain, payment-integration

In the [Monero URI](http://monero.wikia.com/wiki/URI_formatting), is the tx_description stored on the blockchain?  If so, is it encrypted?  What is the maximum length of this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monero: URI is not a transaction, it is a descriptor for how to create a transaction with some particular parameters.

The description is not stored in the blockchain. Of course, some software might decide to put this in a transaction, but that's on it.

It is not encrypted.

There is no defined maximum length, but some parsers might have limits.